# Filling PDF with AutoIT scripts

Tags: pdf, autoit

I am trying to fill a PDF fillable form using AUtoIT by using scripts. To make my agents works easy going. I ma trying to fill the pdf fields. Initially I am testing on single field **Fname_c[0]** ,but its not filling with value

Below is the code what i tried

```
$FilePath = "Form.pdf"
If $FilePath =-1 Then
   MsgBox(0, "Error", "No file.")
   Exit
EndIf
$fieldname = "Fname_C[0]"
$fileOut = "Form2.pdf"
$App = ObjCreate("AcroExch.App")
$AVDoc = ObjCreate("AcroExch.AVDoc")
If $AVDoc.Open($FilePath, "") Then
$PDDoc = $AVDoc.GetPDDoc
$AForm = ObjCreate("AFormAut.App")
$EX = "" _
         & ' var f = this.getField("' & $fieldname & '")' & @LF _
         & ' f.value = "Sunil"'

$AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript($EX)
$PDDoc.save(1, $fileOut)
$App.closeAlldocs()
$App.exit()
Else
MsgBox(0, "", "Coudn't open report")

 EndIf
;; release objects
$AForm = 0
$AVDoc = 0
$PDDoc = 0
$App = 0
```

where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Where exactly is the error pointing to? Please edit the error message formatting as it's unclear.

Comment: sorry the error i found which is because of i am using adobe reader, i install Acrobat its working. I am trying to add text to to a particular field in pdf by using  ** $fieldname = "Fname_C[0]" ** and running js 
`$EX = "" _
         & ' var f = this.getField("' & $fieldname & '")' & @LF _
         & ' f.value = "Sunil"'
`
but the field value is not filling in pdf